# CORS error in js code

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            url:    "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=D:\MS4W\Apache\htdocs\baseWFS.map&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=getfeature&TYPENAME=parcel&bbox=518259.145000,3240058.724100,519352.395700,3241604.305400,EPSG:4326&outputformat=geojson",
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
        });

        var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource,
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)',
                    width: 2
                })
            })
        });
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [vector],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [518744, 3240850],
                maxZoom: 10,
                zoom : 1            
            }),
            target: document.getElementById('map')
        });
```

I wrote this js code but it's not show anything and have this error :
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=D:MS4WApachehtdocsLIS_project%08aseWFS.map&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=getfeature&TYPENAME=parcel&bbox=518259.145000,3240058.724100,519352.395700,3241604.305400,EPSG:4326&outputformat=geojson. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: Let me know the complete code, I'll help you to add CORS headers, I mean how you are making the request, any client like 'request'? Please provide complete information about client and server.

Comment: By any chance are you running this script via a `file://` url?  CORS is disallowed for that protocol.  If you use localhost for both (or otherwise keep everything on the same domain name)  you won't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a server side problem. Allow client domain on your server side. Also check this https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: I do that but the problem is not fixed

Answer (score -1):

Just add CORS plugin to chrome, use below link and enable it from chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

It just reduces the pain of doing it manually.

Answer (score -1):

RE: "It's quite straight, CORS headers are missing while making a request. Please add CORS from the CLIENT end!!??..." NO you're suggesting a basic rookie error I've seen over and over...
CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is a way for the SERVER to say “I will accept your request, even though you came from a DIFFERENT origin.” e.g. Web API service runs on SERVER port 5000 and CLIENT runs on port 4200... This requires cooperation and configuration from the SERVER – so if you CANNOT modify the SERVER (e.g. if you’re using an external API), this approach WON'T work. Some suggested disabling CORS security options on CLIENT browser for development purpose..., still it's not recommended and pretty risky as you leave the front door wide opened.